# How to fix loss not going down when training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

When I'm training my autoencoder the loss doesn't change at all no matter how much I train it.

```
#Importing training data
inp = open('train.csv',"rb")
X = pickle.load(inp)
X = X/255.0
X = np.array(X)
X = np.reshape(X,(-1,25425))


input_img =tf.keras.layers.Input(25425,)
encoded1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(75,activation=tf.nn.relu)(input_img)
encoded2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation=tf.nn.relu)(encoded1)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25425, activation='sigmoid')(encoded2)
# The input of the autoencoder is the image (input_img), and the output is the decoder layer (decoded)
autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, decoded)

encoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, encoded2)

encoded_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(50,))
# The decoded only consists of the last layer
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1](encoded_input)
# The input to the decoder is the vector of the encoder which will be fed (using encoded_input), the output is the last layer of the network (decoder_layer)
decoder = tf.keras.Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(X, X, epochs=50, shuffle=True)

# Save the weights
autoencoder.save_weights('model_weights.h5')

# Save the model architecture
with open('model_architecture.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(autoencoder.to_json())
```

I am hoping that I can get the training to work better But my loss is stuck at 0.6932

Comment: The output dimensions increase tremendously from 50 to 25425. Also, do not use ReLU with sigmoid.

Answer (score 0):

Autoencoders are tasked with *compressing input size* while *minimizing information loss*. What your decoder attempts to do is to reconstruct `25425` points from only `50` points - that is over a **500-fold** compression, which is highly unrealistic. I also assume your input is normalized between `(0,1)`, as the sigmid cannot reach beyond.

**Solution**: change decoder *and* encoder # of units so that the ratio, `input_dim/min_units`, is "reasonable" (say, 5:1). `min_units` = # of units of the layer with least units (encoder or decoder) - in your case, 50. (*Note*: `25425` is quite large - consider dimensionality reduction via downsampling (e.g. `MaxPooling`), or using convolutional autoencoders)

Regarding ReLU with sigmoid, fine to use both, but take some caution with exploding gradients/activations in ReLU via e.g. weight decay - see [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144733/can-i-use-relu-in-autoencoder-as-activation-function).